# PostgreSQL 9.x - pg_read_binary_file & inserting files into bytea

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I have been looking everywhere (google, stackoverflow, etc.) for some documentation on how to use the PostgreSQL `pg_read_binary_file()` function.

The only meaningful thing I can find is [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE-TABLE) in the official documentation.

Every time I try to use this function I get an error.

For example:

```
    SELECT pg_read_binary_file('/some/path/and/file.gif');
    ERROR:  absolute path not allowed
```

or

```
    SELECT pg_read_binary_file('file.gif');
    ERROR:  could not stat file "file.gif": No such file or directory
```

Do I need to have my file in a specific directory for Postgres to have access to it? If so what directory?

---

If it matters, the reason I am looking at this function is because I am trying to insert a file into the database without [doing crazy things](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2962).

Comment: Are you aware that the file is supposed to be located on the *server*, not on the client where you run the SQL statement? Additionally: "*only files within the database cluster directory and the log_directory can be accessed*"

Comment: From [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) "Only files within the database cluster directory and the log_directory can be accessed. Use a relative path for files in the cluster directory, and a path matching the log_directory configuration setting for log files.". The file must be on PGDATA directory.

Comment: You are both correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @losthorse could you post this an an answer?  I would be happy to upvote.

Comment: @ChrisTravers - I have added the answer... I'm glad you found this helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated by @a_horse_with_no_name and @guedes the solution is to ensure that the file being uploaded is on the server in the PGDATA directory.

The [postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) does state the file location as a requirement.

Additionally, I made a symlink from another directory to the PGDATA directory so that I would not disturb any of the postgres data structure. This seems to be working well and I don't have to do any of the above [crazy things](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2962).