# How to convert OID dat type to XML in postgres?

Tags: xml, postgresql, casting, oid

I'm using Postgres 9.5.

This is my Postgres Table.

```
create table testXml(XmlFile xml);
```

I have an XML file in my local Folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><Student><Id>1</Id><Marks>275</Marks><Rank>2</Rank></Student>
```

I want insert the file into my table. I can able to insert the file when it located in the data directory.

I found an alternate way but it returns OID value:

```
SELECT lo_import('/home/dinesh/Desktop/test.xml');
```

When runs this, it gives the result : `17994`

But I need the XML value as my result.

I can't able to find a clear solution to convert the OID to XML value.

Please help me to get the correct result.

Thanks in Advice.

Comment: I think the answer to your question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048649/postgresql-9-x-pg-read-binary-file-inserting-files-into-bytea

Comment: You can't use `lo_import` with the `xml` type (and `lo_import` can only access files on the server anyway).